# React-Cesium webpack config loader issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, config, loader, cesiumjs

I'm new to playing with Webpack configuration and attempting to incorporate [React-Cesium](http://httphttps://github.com/rot1024/cesium-react) into my project. I'm following along with the Github instructions for installing React-Cesium and running into this error: 
[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js file after adding what the documentation told me to:

```
'use strict';

const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    externals: {
      cesium: "Cesium"
    },
    output: {
       publicPath: "/"
         // ...
    },
    alias: {
      cesiumSource: "cesium",
      cesium: "cesium/Cesium"
    },
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          'pug-loader?self'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },

    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
    new CopyPlugin([
     {
       from: `node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium${prod ? "" : "Unminified"}`,
       to: "cesium"
     }
   ]),
   new HtmlIncludeAssetsPlugin({
     append: false,
     assets: [
       "cesium/Widgets/widgets.css",
       "cesium/Cesium.js"
     ]
   }),
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     "process.env": {
       NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(opts && prod ? "production" : "development"),
       CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify("/cesium")
     }
   })

 }
  ],

};
```

The documentation is a little ambiguous and I'm not sure what's wrong. The documentation says to install **npm i html-include-assets-plugin --save-dev**. That command doesn't work, I get a 404 error when attempting to install it.

Is that what is causing the loader error? If not, then what is?

Comment: Can you share your .babelrc

Comment: I'm very new to webpack/babel config. Not sure how I'd locate that file. I'm doing a search in my project directory and there's no .babelrc file. I have 30 or 40 babel folders in my project though.

Comment: Did you fix this? If so, how? This is a very common problem with Cesium and Webpack